# Unable to click on element when array value is returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I retrieve the first index value from an array of items on a search results page
`@searchresultspage.search_results[0]`

I am trying to click on one of the elements (product name) inside this array value and the get the error message below.

```
undefined method `product_name' for #<PageObjects::Sections::SearchResultsPage::SearchResults:0x007f976e8a8380> (NoMethodError)
```

Please see this code below of where I am calling my methods.

```
require 'site_prism'
require_relative 'sections/search_results/search_results'

module PageObjects
  class SearchResultsPage < SitePrism::Page

    sections :search_results, 
    PageObjects::Sections::SearchResultsPage::SearchResults, '.s-item-
    container'

    element :product_name, '.a-row a-spacing-none'

      def first_line_item
        search_results[0]
      end

      def choosing_first_line_item
        search_results[0].product_name.click
      end
  end
end
```

Can somebody provide any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the SitePrism README](https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#sections), any `elements` you wish to associate with a `section` should be defined in the section itself. You're adding your `:product_name` element in a `page`. Try something like this:

```
class SearchResultSection < SitePrism::Section
  element :product_name, '.a-row .a-spacing-none'
end

class SearchResultsPage < SitePrism::Page
  sections :search_results, SearchResultSection

  def first_product_name
    search_results.first.product_name
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However I have tried your method and I am getting the following error.    `undefined method 'product_name' for #<PageObjects::Sections::SearchResultsPage::SearchResults:0x007ff078b3e118> (NoMethodError)`. I have attached a link to my git repo please can you take a look [link](https://github.com/shafiqahmedmalik2010/amazon_test)

Comment: @ShafiqAhmedMalik [Your section class definition has no methods.](https://github.com/shafiqahmedmalik2010/amazon_test/blob/master/features/page_objects/sections/search_results/search_results.rb)

Comment: I have added the methods to the section class but now getting `undefined method 'product_name'`